# Creating custom Code Analysis rules for XAML

Tags: unit-testing, xaml, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, code-analysis

I'm interested in creating custom rules for Code Analysis (`Visual Studio 2010` and above) ***which target the XAML specifically***.

I've read about [creating custom rules](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/03/26/how-to-write-custom-static-code-analysis-rules-and-integrate-them-into-visual-studio-2010.aspx) and even about FXCop + [XAML Toolkit](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/XAML), but the later is now archived and doesn't support latest versions of FXCop (i.e. the version that Code Analysis works with).
I've also looked at other tools such as [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx) but it doesn't seem to support this either.

An example for a custom rule I'd like to make:
*Make sure no elements in the XAML have the **Width** property set to a constant.*

Any ideas on how to do this in `VS 2012/VS 2013` (any external tool that integrates with Visual studio is also an option)?

Answer (score 0):

Our code analysis product http://submain.com/CodeIt.Right includes a set of XAML/SL/WPF rules out of the box and you can also create the custom rule you mention using CodeIt.Right custom rule SDK. We'd be happy to walk you through your custom rule.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a CodeAnalysis rule, a StyleCop rule is probably what you're after. CodeAnalysis works on the compiled code, which makes it harder to verify the xaml code.

StyleCop works on the source code, allowing you to craft checks with something as simple as XPath to validate something like the presence of an attribute or the value.